# Sort table in javascript, some columns asc and some desc

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I have an array of javascript objects:

```
             var json= [
               {
                 "name": "xyz", 
                 "pay": 40, 
                 "rate": 5000, 
                 "totals": 50000 
                },
                { 

                 "name": "abc", 
                 "pay": 30, 
                 "rate": 1400, 
                 "totals": 100000 
                                 }
                ];
```

I have bee able to set this out in a table in javascript successfully:

```
            var mytable = $('<table></table>').attr({ id: "myTable" });
            var rows = Object.keys(dataSet).length;
            var cols = dataSet.length;
            var tr = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
                var row = $('<tr></tr>').appendTo(mytable);
                row.
                append($('<td>').text(json[i].name)).
                append($('<td>').text(json[i].pay)).
                append($('<td>').text(json[i].rate)).
                append($('<td>').text(json[i].totals)).appendTo(mytable);


            }
            $('body').append(mytable);
                         function sortTable(){
                var $table = $('#myTable');
                console.log($table);
                var $rows = $('tbody > tr',$table);
                $rows.sort(function(a, b){
                    var keyA = $('td',a).text();
                    var keyB = $('td',b).text();
                    return (keyA > keyB) ? 1 : 0;

                });
                $.each($rows, function(index, row){
                  $table.append(row);
                });
            } //this just sorts name alphabetically
```

But I need to sort some columns in the desc order and some in the asc order on the initial load.

Name should be sorted alphabetically, pay and rate in ascending order and totals in descending. I am not able to figure out a correct way of doing this, I cannot use the jquery tablesorter.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the data coming from a database? It would probably be easier to sort it in the SQL query.

Comment: If not, use the Javascript `Array:sort()` method to sort `json` before creating the table. You can supply a comparison function that compares the properties in the appropriate order.

Comment: Not for now, I have say five more elements say in the json array.

Comment: BTW, you're appending the row to the table twice -- first when you initialize the variable, and again after you append all the columns.

Comment: Does your input data actually have multiple entries with the same name? Sorting by multiple columns only makes sense if the primary sort field has duplicates, then you sort within those.

Answer (score 0):

Sort the data before creating the table:

```
function compareRow(a, b) {
    if (a.name != b.name) {
        return a.name > b.name ? 1 : -1; // Ascending by name
    }
    if (a.pay != b.pay) {
        return a.pay - b.pay; // Ascending by pay within same name
    }
    if (a.rate != b.rate) {
        return a.rate - b.rate; // Ascending by rate within same name and pay
    }
    return b.totals - a.totals; // Descending by totals within same name, pay, and rate
}
json.sort(compareRow);
```